# Selecting a Face and Extruding a Cube in Blender Via Python API

Tags: python, blender

I am working on a project in which I will need to be able to extrude the faces of a cube via the python API.

I have managed to extrude a plane via the API:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select = True # Select the default Blender Cube
bpy.ops.object.delete() # Delete the selected objects (default blender Cube) 

#Define vertices and faces
verts = [(0,0,0),(0,5,0),(5,5,0),(5,0,0)]
faces = [(0,1,2,3)]

# Define mesh and object variables
mymesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Plane")
myobject = bpy.data.objects.new("Plane", mymesh)  

#Set scene of object
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(myobject)

#Create mesh
mymesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
mymesh.update(calc_edges=True)

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects['Plane']

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.data.objects['Plane'].select = True # Select the default Blender Cube
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 2)})
```

I have built my Cube in a similar way but my issue is I can't work out how to select a face to extrude via the Python API

Please find my Cube Code http://pastebin.com/PQtMcRAh

All Help is Appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you need here, but if you need this:

[image]

Then this is the code you need:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select = True # Select the default Blender Cube
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete() # Delete the selected objects (default blender Cube)

#Define vertices, faces, edges
verts = [(0,0,0),(0,5,0),(5,5,0),(5,0,0),(0,0,5),(0,5,5),(5,5,5),(5,0,5)]
faces = [(0,1,2,3), (4,5,6,7), (0,4,5,1), (1,5,6,2), (2,6,7,3), (3,7,4,0)]

#Define mesh and object
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Cube")
object = bpy.data.objects.new("Cube", mesh)

#Set location and scene of object
object.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(object)

#Create mesh
mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube'] # Select the default Blender Cube

#Enter edit mode to extrude
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False)

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
for face in bm.faces:
    face.select = False
bm.faces[1].select = True

# Show the updates in the viewport
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, True)

bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_faces_move(MESH_OT_extrude_faces_indiv={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value":-5, "use_even_offset":True, "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "release_confirm":False})
```

It expands upon your code. To explain:

After you code, it:

1. Uses `bmesh` to modify the mesh (`bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)`)
2. Deselect all faces (`for face in bm.faces: face.select = False`)
3. Selects the top face (`bm.faces[1].select = True`)
4. Updates the viewport so you can see it (`bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, True)`)
5. Extrudes the top face by 5 units (`bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_faces_move(MESH_OT_extrude_faces_indiv={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_shrink_fatten={"value": -VALUE, "use_even_offset":True, "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "release_confirm":False})`)

In order to change the number of units extruded, you can modify the `VALUE` variable.